# Last letter getting erased when you tab to the next textbox in Account shipping address

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am filling out the Shipping Address texboxes of a standard Account object.

When I type a value in and then tab to the next textbox, the last letter of the entered object is getting deleted. See image below
[image]

I deactiveted the flows and processes tied to the Account object. The Account object also has no Triggers, or Validation Rules associated with it, and there are no Platform Events. The problem still persists.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Try on another device?

Comment: I am only seeing the issue on one trailhead org and not another. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what could be triggering this on the client side. Triggers, validation rules,, formula fields all get processed  on the server right?

Comment: What process could be capturing the tab from one textbox to another and acting on it?